Electron Renderer Process Gone with exit code 134
My electron app goes blank after 6-8 hours of activity on a device thats open all day. I'm recieving a crash log with exit code 134.
When I log the heap used, it keeps on increasing overtime.
Memory Usage: RSS: 85323776 bytes, Heap Total: 11988992 bytes, Heap Used: 10529512 bytes
Renderer process gone, error: {}, details:{"reason":"crashed","exitCode":134}


Its a very lightweight electron app that spins up a react app in the renderer. Not sure what's wrong, i dont have any warnings/errors other than the crash.
Also every here and then im seeing this
Check failed: false. NOTREACHED log messages are omitted in official builds. Sorry!

Does anyone have any idea about what these are.

Exit code 134  means the process got a SIGABRT signal, but that does not necessarily answer why it got one.

@OfNothing yeah i figured that after abit of reading but still doesnt explain why. Its pretty vague
